# Can't find LESS bootstrap 3 files in download

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Ok so this is more a general question then an issue with code however I used the compiler on Bootstrap 3 website and changed the point at which the navbar collapses and goes mobile or whatever you want to call it.

This worked fine I re-uploaded the new bootstrap files over the old one (of course any additional changes to CSS are defined in a separate styles.css sheet so that is safe and sound.

My question is I keep reading everywhere that I should have .less files yet my changes work perfectly and I just have css js and font files containing files like bootstrap.css bootstrap.min.css and so on.

Where are these less files I am meant to have? Or is this only in an older version of Bootstrap for example.

If someone can shred some light on this that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.1.1.zip here you finde the less files. 
Less is a CSS pre-processor, which can handle Variables etc. So Less Files can be compiled to css.
So you don't need them if you edit the css directly.

Comment: Thank you for responding nice to know there are people out there willing to offer help to those getting to grips with Bootstrap. Thanks once again. A real asset to StackOverFlow!